# Nvidia-smi fail to detect Gpu

Tags: gpu

I work with tensorflow it is not deticting Gpu
Nvidia-smi is showing this
what should I do

[image]

[image: pip install --user tensorflow-gpu]

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the screenshot your Nvidia driver is properly installed (since, using nvidia-smi, you are able to see the driver specifics and that there is a running process with access to the GPU).

However, aside from having the Nvidia driver installed, you also need to install the CUDA-Toolkit and the cuDNN library. They are available for download - https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit, https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn.

If CUDA is properly installed, maybe your Tensorflow installation is incompatible with the installed CUDA? Check here - https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

If above do not apply, I would suggest verifying that you have a GPU-enabled version of Tensorflow installed (Tensorflow-GPU). You can test whether Tensorflow is able to detect your GPU - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available.

Comment: I installed latest cuda, cudnn, visualstudio, and tensflow, latest version of tenseflow included Gpu as I understand but also I tried to run pip install tensflow-gpu but gives me error.    now I don't know what is the problem to make gpu work in python

Comment: Can you post the tensorflow-gpu error message?

Comment: I put it up , it is the second image

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem like a GPU-related issue necessarily. If you try installing another python package (perhaps a simpler package, for testing purposes, outside the Anaconda interface) and get the same error message - that would imply it's a Python-Windows specific issue regarding permissions.

Comment: I will try to change cuda version from 11 to 10 maybe it's the problem

Comment: Neither CUDA version 10.0 nor 10.1 seem to be marked as compatible with Python3.8. I would try installing tensorflow-gpu=2.4.0, as version 2.4.1 seems to be experimental.

Comment: I will check that too